# Why does the [sqlserver.types] tag have a period in it?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I noticed that the [sqlserver.types](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver.types) tag has a period in it. Most other tags have hyphens, like [sql-server](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) and [sql-server-spatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-spatial).

Should the [sqlserver.types](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sqlserver.types) tag be changed to [sql-server-types](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-types)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [tag naming conventions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) say to:

> - Avoid punctuation (which can make it difficult to use the tag in a URL)

which suggests that reviewing that tag name is desirable.

I think we should:

1. At minimum, use a hyphen before `types` and also between `sql` and `server` in the tag name
2. Preferably burninate the tag name instead  by replacing it on six questions with existing tags of [geometry-data-type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-data-type) and/or [geography-data-type](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography-data-type)